# A map within a map from an array, within an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, array-map

ReactJS Newbie here. Basically, I have an array. Then another array within it. Please see below:

```
arr = [{
   itema: 'a',
   itemb: ['img/image1.jpg', 'img/image2.jpg']
}, {
   itema: 'b',
   itemb: ['img/image3.jpg', 'img/image4.jpg', 'img/image5.jpg']
}, {
   itema: 'c',
   itemb: ['img/image6.jpg', 'img/image7.jpg']
}
]
```

I've successfully mapped the array above, like this:

```
arr.map((arr, i) => {
   return(<span>{arr.itema}</span>)
})
```

But my problem is the inner-map. Is it possible to map this array within the given array?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can.

```
arr.map((item, i) => {
   return (
     <div>
         <span>{item.itema}</span>
         {
            item.itemb && item.itemb.length > 0 &&
            item.itemb.map(image => (<img src={image} />))
         }
     </div>
    );
})
```

This will rendered like below (for only one item in arr)

```
  <div>
   <span>a</span>
   <img src="img/image1.jpg" />
   <img src="img/image2.jpg" />
  </div>
```

And I noticed that you used same item name `arr` as parent array `arr` in first map function. I recommend to use different key name to identify correctly.

Comment: One more question. I'm new to Reactjs and basically know a thing or two now. In your code,  what does this mean -- "item.itemb && arr.itemb.length > 0 &&".  Thanks.

Comment: @DaveMoreno Oops! It was a typo. I updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, but what does this line means if I'm gonna use it for future references?  Really appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: @DaveMoreno It's a kind of validation, in my codes it only renders image array only when it has valid values like your sample data. when there is no `itemb` or there's no items in `itemb`, there's no need to render them. :D
And If I didn't validate `itemb` then it will occur a bug when callding `item.itemb.map()` function. It is recommended to validate before rendering.

Comment: Thanks. Great help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ofcourse it is possible to show nested arrays in React or any other framework.
For e.g. in your `render` function

```
render() {
 return (
 <>
  {
   arr.map((arr, i) =>(
      <> 
       <span>{arr.itema}</span>
       <span>{arr.itemb.map(item => (<span>{item}</span>))}</span>
      </>
    )
  }
 </>
 )
}
```

Comment: This is very useful.  However, after I deleted one image array, making it blank like this-- itemb: [''], it produces an error. But if not, your code works flawlessly.  Thanks.